# NSMutableURLRequest returning JSON with empty sub-arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I have created a method that uses NSMutableURLRequest to request and receive JSON from a RESTful API running on a remote machine. The request successfully returns some JSON, but the returned sub-arrays in the JSON (see tasks: []) are empty.

The JSON returned from the API is:

```
{
   "error":false,
   "tasks":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "task":"Get Milk",
         "status":0,
         "createdAt":"2014-08-09 12:29:15"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "task":"Call Mom",
         "status":0,
         "createdAt":"2014-08-09 12:46:52"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "task":"Call Dad",
         "status":0,
         "createdAt":"2014-08-09 12:47:04"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "task":"Study",
         "status":0,
         "createdAt":"2014-08-09 12:47:08"
      }
   ]
}
```

The method that utilizies NSMutableURLRequest (proper parameters being passed is assumed) is:

```
-(NSDictionary *) apiRequestWithEndpoint:(NSString *) endpoint
                              withParams:(NSDictionary *) params
                         withHTTPHeaders:(NSDictionary *) headers
                          withHTTPMethod:(NSString *) method
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endpoint]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];

    //set headers
    for (id key in headers) {
        [request setValue:[headers valueForKey:key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
    }

    //set paramaters in request body
    NSMutableString *requestBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    int keyIndex = 0;
    for (id key in params) {
        if (keyIndex == 0) {
            [requestBody appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [params valueForKey:key]];
        } else {
            [requestBody appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, [params valueForKey:key]];
        }
        keyIndex++;
    }

    [request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *NSURLError = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&NSURLError];
    if (NSURLError) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ Cancelling operation.", NSURLError);
        return nil;
    }

    NSError *NSJSONSerializationError = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&NSJSONSerializationError];

    if (NSJSONSerializationError) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ Cancelling operation.", NSJSONSerializationError);
        return nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Data: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    return responseJSON;
}
```

Notice the 4th last line that logs the returned NSData from the NSMutableURLRequest, the output is:

> Data: {"error":false "tasks":[]}

The code that calls the above method:

```
NSString *getAllTasksEndpoint = @"http://developmentVPS.com/TaskList-API/v1/tasks";
NSString *apiKey = @"A Valid API Key";

NSDictionary *headers = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:apiKey, @"Authorization", nil];

NSDictionary *responseJSON = [self apiRequestWithEndpoint:getAllTasksEndpoint
                                               withParams:nil
                                          withHTTPHeaders:headers
                                           withHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

It is my understanding that the entire data returned from the request should be logged in that NSLog call, but "tasks" is empty. I am new to iOS development, so I may be missing something simple. Does anybody see anything I am missing here?

Comment: NSLog would print the subarray contents if they exist. How do you know that the API is returning tasks? That is, how did you get the JSON example above?

Comment: @PatrickGoley I got the JSON above from the "Advanced Rest Client" Chrome plugin after sending the same request using the plugin that I am trying to send in the code, let me update the question with the exact call

Comment: It's telling you that there are no tasks for whatever selection criteria you provided.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, after checking the API key I am getting in response to posting to a login endpoint, I noticed that it is in fact a different key than what I was expecting. To make a long story short I was looking at the wrong user's tasks and you are quite correct that there were indeed no tasks for the particular user associated with the API key.

If you would like to answer the question I will mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Using something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) could help you understand what is going wrong with your request.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Thank you for the link, Charles does indeed look extremely useful